# How to crack a docx file password

Tags: encryption

so I have a docx file protected by a password to be unlocked. I forgot the password but I was able to get the encryption information by renaming it to .zip then extracting this information:

```
  @   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>

<encryption xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/encryption"

xmlns:p="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/keyEncryptor/password"
 xmlns:c="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/keyEncryptor/certificate">

<keyData saltSize="16" blockSize="16" keyBits="128" hashSize="20"
 cipherAlgorithm="AES" cipherChaining="ChainingModeCBC" hashAlgorithm="SHA1"
 saltValue="/dDzGMibWEFXf4sm0BEylA=="/><dataIntegrity
 encryptedHmacKey="broUgedNr5RzcezbcRJaoqV/HxPnu6THAgQ8UHiUmMQ="
 encryptedHmacValue="dN3puo1gHZYzKKN/I5Mg02wv3hLwVFqzXH8ZAxnnvq0="/>
<keyEncryptors><keyEncryptor
 uri="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/keyEncryptor/password">

<p:encryptedKey spinCount="100000" saltSize="16" blockSize="16" keyBits="128"
 hashSize="20" cipherAlgorithm="AES" cipherChaining="ChainingModeCBC"
 hashAlgorithm="SHA1" saltValue="ylP7x+mnXKd09MX8T6bymg=="
 encryptedVerifierHashInput="yS06pumzwHVy0hsIilW8qA=="
 encryptedVerifierHashValue="ctAj9mt2PgsZB0QfijIVWT8SxhiRNlamlAEovebWbs4="
 encryptedKeyValue="uEw2U5xY5owBXcgIo/XryQ=="/></keyEncryptor></keyEncryptors>
</encryption>
```

anything should I understand from the text above? is there a hash value that I can decrypt with let's say johnny the ripper?

Answer (score 1):

This software for Windows is very good with that: https://www.elcomsoft.com/aopr.html

Is paid software, you can download a trial [here](https://www.elcomsoft.com/download/aopr_setup_en.msi).

For linux you can try to do it with hashcat. See [this](http://pentestcorner.com/cracking-microsoft-office-97-03-2007-2010-2013-password-hashes-with-hashcat/).